# array of text field can't send to php includes file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an array of text fields (user interface) that created HTML, CSS, Javascript using inside of the user interfaces.

The problem is when input elements that don't print or send the whole array. I want to print the whole array. It prints one array element.

order.php (user interface):

```
    <div class="row">               
            <form id="ex_order" action="includes/exchange-order.inc.php" method="POST">

            <div id="main_div" class="main_sec_div">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-ml-12">
                    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-ml-12 group">
                    <div class="row" style="padding:0rem 1rem 1rem 1rem; padding-bottom:1.5rem; margin:2rem 0.2rem 2rem 0.2rem; background:#ccc;">
                            <div class="col-12 mt-5" style="margin:-1rem;">
                                    <span style="margin-left:1rem;" class="status-p bg-primary">Passanger #1</span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add Ticket Information start -->
                            <div class="col-3 mt-5">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h4 class="header-title">Ticket Infromation</h4>
                                                    <p class="text-muted font-14 mb-4">Here are want to add <code>Ticket Infromation</code> of Exchange Order.</p>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label">Passenger Name</label>
                                                            <input name="p_name[]" class="form-control" type="text" id="p_name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="validationCustom03">Ticket No.</label>
                                                            <input name="ticket_no[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_no" required>
                                                    </div>

                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="submitOrder" id="submitOrder" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 pr-4 pl-4">Save</button>


<!-- Jquery -->
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                let i = 0;
                let passCount = 1;
                console.log('Default i : ', i);

                // add button
                $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
                        i++;
                        console.log('Add', i);
                        html = `
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-ml-12 second-div" id="sec_div${i}">
                                <div class="row" style="padding:0rem 1rem 1rem 1rem; padding-bottom:1.5rem; margin:2rem 0.2rem 2rem 0.2rem; background:#ccc;">
                                        <div class="col-12 mt-5" style="margin:-1rem; display:flex; height:60px; align-items:center; align-content:center; justify-content:space-between;">
                                                <div>
                                                        <span style="margin-left:1rem;" class="status-p bg-primary">Passanger #${++passCount}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                        <button style="margin:1rem 1rem 0 0;" type="button" name="remove" id="${i}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-3 mt-5">
                                                <div class="card">
                                                        <div class="card-body">
                                                                <h4 class="header-title">Ticket Infromation</h4>
                                                                <p class="text-muted font-14 mb-4">Here are want to add <code>Ticket Infromation</code> of Exchange Order.</p>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label">Passenger Name</label>
                                                                        <input name="p_name[]" class="form-control" type="text" id="p_name" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                                                        <label for="validationCustom03">Ticket No.</label>
                                                                        <input name="ticket_no[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_no" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>`;

                        $('#main_div').append(html);
                });
        });
</script>
```

order.inc.php (php includes file) :

```
<?php

// Save Button
if (isset($_POST['submitOrder'])) {

    // passenger
    $p_name = $_POST['p_name'];
    $ticket_no = $_POST['ticket_no'];

    var_dump($p_name);
    echo '<br/>';
    var_dump($ticket_no);
    echo '<br/>';



    foreach ($p_name as $key => $value) {
        echo $p_name[$key];
        echo $ticket_no[$key];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any problems with this code (changed form action only) beside single merged prints that go like `namenumber` (temporary fix with `echo $p_name[$key] . ' ';`)

Comment: I've tried although it returns the first index of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem which returns whole array element to send to PHP includes file.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "6386868" [1]=> string(6) "868768" }

array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "6868" [1]=> string(4) "6868" }
```

**The problem is the DOM element**.
I don't put the `<form>` tag into currect place. When I click the add button, jquery is adding out of `<form>` tag.

**Solution:**
I changed the `<form>` tag outside of bootstrap `<div>` tag which works fine that returns whole array element.